# Open a PDF and Print Preview jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, printing, reportviewer

I'm currently working with the ReportViewer control in an MVC3 enviroment. I've got it working along with navigation and exporting, my problem is my boss wants me to "automate" the printing or reports by opening up the PDF to the print preview.

I currently have a way to Export the Report as a PDF in Javascript.

```
$find('1_ReportViewer').exportReport("PDF")
```

This downloads the Report as a PDF. I was wondering if there was a way in Javascript/JQuery to automatically open the PDF and bring up the Print Preview.

I've been reading around and I'm only finding solutions to do this server-sided or with plugins. Is a plugin my only solution?

I've tried something along the lines of,

```
window.open($find('1_ReportViewer').exportReport("PDF"));
```

but come up short of success.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to open this pdf in browser for viewing/printing or locally on the machine?

Comment: I want to be able to open it for Viewing/Printing on the Local machine. I can download the PDF to the local machine I just need to automate the opening of it. I'm not sure where to start. Are downloaded files selectable through javascript/jquery? I'm assuming not, but I don't know enough about JQuery and Files to rule it out.

Comment: My initial guess would be that you cannot do this with just javascript/jquery but I'm not 100% certain. I'll have to look into this.

Comment: I figured this too, but I thought it was worth asking since I also was told that you couldn't use ReportViewer in MVC hehe. I'll look more into Server-Sided solutions see if it's not too much of a hassle.

Comment: Just to chyme in: i also don't believe this is possible.